# innerHTML assignment don`t work in UIWebView

Tags: javascript, ios, uiwebview, innerhtml

I have a strange problem with innerHTML in UIWebView
After attempts to assign in innerHTML all the content disappears.

Originally innerHTML of element is not empty and contains text with images and divided into paragraphs.

If I doing this:

```
NSString *jsString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].innerHTML='qwerty';"];
[webview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsString];
```

I have empty innerHTML!

If I doing this:

```
NSString *jsString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].innerHTML=document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].innerHTML;"];
[webview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsString];
```

I have empty innerHTML!

If I doing this:

```
NSString *jsString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].textContent=document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].innerHTML;"];
[webview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsString];
```

in my element I see text with a textual representation HTML tags (as expected)

But I don`` `t understand why assignment to innerHTML don ``t work!